# Why does onItemSelected not fire straight after setSelection?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Why does onItemSelected not fire straight after setSelection on transportMode but only after the populateEditData method has finished?

I need onItemSelected to fire because I dynamically change the dataset for transport company in onItemSelected based on the value selected for transportMode

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   transportMode = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrTransportMode);
   transportModeAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.id.txtvTransporModeSpinner, R.layout.custom_spinner_row_item_mode, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transport_mode_array), "mode");
   transportMode.setAdapter(transportModeAdapter);
   transportMode.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

   transportCompany = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrTransportCompany);
    transportCompanyAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.id.txtvTransportCompany, R.layout.custom_spinner_row_item_company, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transport_bus_companies_array), "company");
    transportCompany.setAdapter(transportCompanyAdapter);

   ....

   if(useActivityForEdit)
        populateEditData();
}

public void populateEditData(int modeIndex, int companyIndex)
{
   //Two spinners transportMode has onItemSelected listener
   transportMode.setSelection(modeIndex);
   //On item selected should trigger here then complete before setting transport company selection
   transportCompany.setSelection(companyIndex);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int selectedIndex, long arg3) 
{
   //dynamically changes data of transportCompany adapter
   if(transportMode.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("bus"))
   {    
    transportCompanyAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.id.txtvContent, R.layout.custom_spinner_row_item_company, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transport_bus_companies_array), "company");
    transportCompany.setAdapter(transportCompanyAdapter);
    transportCompany.setClickable(true);
   }
   else if(transportMode.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("train"))
   {
    transportCompanyAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.id.txtvContent, R.layout.custom_spinner_row_item_company, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transport_train_companies_array), "company");
    transportCompany.setAdapter(transportCompanyAdapter);
    transportCompany.setClickable(true);
   }
   else if(transportMode.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("tram"))
   {
    transportCompanyAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.id.txtvContent, R.layout.custom_spinner_row_item_company, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.transport_tram_companies_array), "company");
    transportCompany.setAdapter(transportCompanyAdapter);
    transportCompany.setClickable(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to trigger spinner on item click ? Or do you want click same item in spinner?

Comment: try to call `transportMode.performClick();`

Comment: I want to trigger on item selected. ps: the hard coded values are just to simplify.

it does trigger but only after the populateEditData method has completed.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is, the dataset does get changed / updated but only after I've set the selection for transportCompany on it's original default dataset.

This results in correct item being selected on wrong dataset then dataset updates so item 0 is now selected from correct dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `transportCompany.setAdapter(transportCompanyAdapter);` after `transportCompany.setSelection(companyIndex);`

and adding `transportMode.setAdapter(transportModeAdapter);` after `transportMode.setSelection(modeIndex);`